# Invalid Argument using ditto

Tags: macos, backup, script

I'm using a backup script on my server that uses ditto and I keep getting the following error:

```
ditto: /Volumes/BKP/Daily_bkp.051114/VM Share/Machine/Backups/backup_copies.cmd: Invalid argument
```

This is my code

```
/usr/bin/ditto -V --rsrc "$VMSHARE"  "$DLY_BKP/VM Share" > $DLOG 2> $TMPLOG
err=$?
```

I'm using double quotes to deal with the spaces in the directory name and this file is the only one ditto is having an issue with. I checked the backup and it actually backed up the file no problem, so I'm stumped as to why I keep getting this error. The file doesn't ever change and I've made sure nothing is using it at the time of the backup.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, the file in question had extended metadata on it and that is what caused the problem. I attempted using the --norsrc and --noextattr flags, but this didn't work. I removed the extended metadata and it is now working without any errors. I don't know if there is a better approach, but to get rid of the metadata I did

```
cat backup_copies.cmd > tmp
rm backup_copies.cmd
mv tmp backup_copies.cmd
```

Comment: Easier way to do it
    xattr -c file